# Jquery Tooltipster hide on click outside area

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

I am using jquery tooltispster (http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster) plugin to reveal some menu on hover. What I need is on hover the tooltip wants to show and the tooltip should hide on clicking outside the area of the tooltip. Is it is possible..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding a click event on the body using .one() and use it to hide your tooltip.
Using **.one()** instead of **.on()** to avoid listening on body clicks for nothing while the tooltip has been hidden (rebind .one() when displaying the tooltip)

Comment: Can you explain in detail. Here is the jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/jm_kumaresh/M4ffx/